# Firestore rules : array of maps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following architecture in my datas :

```
roles :

    0 :
        id : xxx
        name : xxx
   
    1 :
        id : xxx
        name : xxx
```

I want a rule, that allows me to check if the user ID is equal to one of the IDs in roles array, is somebody have an idea ?

Thank you and have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the data structured this way.

One option is to duplicate the "id" values into an array field that contains **only** those strings.

```
roleIds:
  0: id-string-0
  1: id-string-1
```

Then to check if `id` is in that list, you can use [hasAny](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny):

```
allow read: if resource.data.roleIds.hasAny([id]);
```

Comment: So a solution would be to create two lists, one with IDs, and one with the names ?

Comment: You could do that do, if you need the names also.  I only show id strings, because those are required for your rules.